# Firebase Real Time Database not showing existing Database but working fine

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an android application and I am facing some weird issues related to FIREBASE DATABASE. 
I have created a firebase database and added some tables, fields and added some data, like;
Log in with phone authentications etc.
I can use this database with my android app, but I can't be able to see the database. 
I have tried a lot to refresh again and again, but not working.
If someone is using firebase, then please login to the console. firebase and check if you can see it, might be, GOOGLE changes its UI (User Interface).

Help me, please!
It will be a great favor.

[image: What I am seeing on google console firebase]

Comment: any code of what you have tried ? and also if you can paste your logcat will be helpfull

Comment: Gastón Saillén, Everything is okay from android side, just need to view my firebase database!,
I can't be able to see my database on console of firebase.

Comment: can you post a picture from google console of what are you seeing?

Comment: i don't know how to post a picture here, as i am new here. plz guide

Comment: Gastón Saillén, i have edited my post, please check picture, against a blue link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not selecting your project:

[image]

Check if that is your project, or change it.

If it's prompting you to create a database for that project, it is because that is not the project you are working on. You need to select the current project you are working on in order to see your database.

Comment: what happends if you press create database ? i think it should let you see your database if you already have one there

Comment: sir, there are two types of databases here, Cloud Firebase and Real time Database, i have created Real Time Database 7 days ago.. 
my android is accessing this database but, i am not able to view it on the console, that is the main issue i am facing

Comment: i am on that project sir, i am sure about it, 
i have checked twice.
Please open your console if you have and check if you can see it,
i am shocked that not a single database is viewing, i had one more database here as well for another project and not showing this as well.

Comment: Click create database there and then do what Raj says below

Comment: Gastón Saillén, Thank you, issue Solved!

Answer (score 0):

There are two options - 1. Realtime Database i.e. Firebase. 2. Cloud FireStore. You have to select 1 instaed of 2. See the image below

[image]

Comment: Plz verify the project id, there can be two projects with same name but different project id's.@sharjeelrehman

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem. I was worried that all the data might have been deleted. I just left the tab open and after few minutes the database and its children started showing. I think if your database contains a lot of data, it takes time to load the data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on Create Database button and setup rules before you try to save data on database. Remember Your are only setting up rules here not giving any database name.

[image]